# SQL Server 2008 R2 Services stopping

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2

I've been experiencing the following since this morning.

Most text fields in the db had the following text appended to it

```
</title><style>.ali7{position:absolute;clip:rect(441px,auto,auto,407px);}</style><div class=ali7><a href=http://highquality-cialis.com >cialis online</a></div></title><style>.ali7{position:absolute;clip:rect(441px,auto,auto,407px);}</style><div class=ali7
```

I've been trying to remove that text from all text fields but the services keep constantly restarting so that makes it very hard to fix the data.

I tried restoring as well from a backup but I can't do that either, when I select from device and select the .bak file I can't see anything on the list to restore from.

I tried trend micro housecall to see if it is a virus, couldn't find anything.
I've tried installing AVG but gives me an error and can't install.
I've tried scanning with Spybot S&D and nothing seems to appear as an issue.

Comment: That sounds bad. I would definitely disable the SSRS services until you can discover what is mangling your reports. It might be a rogue machine in your network that has write permission in SSRS. Once you have the service stopped, you can try looking at the Catalog table. It should tell you the login of the person that is making the changes. That should narrow down your search before wielding the fist of justice.

Comment: @MartinSoles I have't said anything about Reporting Services. We don't even have that installed.

Comment: I apologize. I misread the tag under your question. Since you are talking about just seeing this in tables, it might not be a virus. it might be a SQL injection attack that was done on some internet facing web site or service.